# Resize Disk on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, lvm

```
df
Filesystem                    1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_cloud-lv_root   51606140 9985252   38999448  21% /
tmpfs                            515252       0     515252   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                        495844   50675     419569  11% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_cloud-lv_home 2059640248  203016 1954813516   1% /home
```

I have own cloud setup but it installs by default at /var/www/html/owncloud. Did not think the default partitioning would make /home the biggest.

Is there a way to shift all of /home to the main root / mount?

Comment: What filesystems?  The fact that the two filesystems appear to be on LVM means this should be pretty easy.

Comment: In order to know the filesystem of each partition, you can pass some extra parameters to `df`: `df --human-readable --print-type`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. But I would recommend against removing LVM-volumes since they make administration a lot easier if used correctly.

Start by creating a temporary directory under /mnt. Sync all the data from /home here (you seem to have enough free space). Then unmount /home and remove the logical volume with `lvremove /dev/mapper/vg_cloud-lv_home`. Remember to remove the /home entry from fstab.

Now you should have LOTS of free space which can be checked with `vgdisplay` :  Free  PE / Size.

Extend the / partition `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_cloud-lv_root` and resize the filesystem to match the new logical volume container `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_cloud-lv_root`

Finally sync over the data from under /mnt to /home and you should be done. Now all of the free space from /home should be moved over to / instead.